# Configue SSH to connect to GitHub failed

Tags: git, ssh

I generate a pair of rsa key,then i put the public key on github,
but when i try `ssh git@github.com`,it still need a passward,like this:

```
$ ssh git@github.com
git@github.com's password:
```

I'm sure i have create correct private key and public key by `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "xxx"`

```
uchin@DESKTOP-UCHIN MINGW64 ~/.ssh
$ ls -lah
total 74K
drwxr-xr-x 1 uchin 197121    0 Sep 30 19:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 uchin 197121    0 Sep 30 19:25 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 uchin 197121  576 Sep 30 19:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 uchin 197121 2.6K Sep 30 19:45 id_rsa.rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 uchin 197121  484 Sep 30 19:46 known_hosts
```

Also i have upload my public key,[github public key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBHLj.png)

I have try many times,but it never works.

Here's some information by `ssh -Tv git@github.com`

```
$ ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to github.com [223.75.236.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:rEmlJenVMSL5GVemSY0Gk8WGw6B4ege4J85M+vup8R0
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ryU3w/a2yayTwFk3eNMI7NoyEugbQgYMrulXT9f/oeY
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ryU3w/a2yayTwFk3eNMI7NoyEugbQgYMrulXT9f/oeY
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@github.com's password:
Connection closed by 223.75.236.241 port 22
```

I want to konw how to make it works,thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ssh outputs does not indicate that ***GitHub server accepts your key***. So please check if you've uploaded the equivalent public key properly.

You can verify if the public key uploaded successfully, by visiting the URL: `https://github.com/<your_github_username>.keys`

For example, assuming your username is `uchin`, then you can see all your public keys at `https://github.com/uchin.keys`

If keys are not matched, then reupload the public key. If they are not, please rerun `ssh -vvv git@github.com`, and share the output here.

Comment: Yes,in another machine, there are a` Server accepts Key` information output,besides `Offering public key`, but this machine not

I went to `https://github.com/myUserName.Keys` and found that the local public key was uploaded correctly,they are same.

The output message is too long by `ssh -vvv`. I compared it with another normal machine and found that the main difference seems like this:

After send a public key packet,here receive package type is 51, but the other normal one is 60，and after it,there is no the server accepts.

Comment: Here is part of the output

`debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ryU3w/a2yayTwFk3eNMI7NoyEugbQgYMrulXT9f/oeY**
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory`


I don't know if there is a problem here.  Should I provide more detailed output information?

Comment: @uchin Are there differences between machines you are using to connect to GitHub? Both are Windows or mixed of Linux and Windows?

Comment: 51 means "key not accepted", that's pretty much all there is to it and is why ssh moves on to the next method.

Comment: @uchin Double check if your private key and the one uploaded are matched. You can get public key from the private key with the following command: `ssh-keygen -y -f /c/Users/uchin/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 1):

Note that

> debug1: Connecting to github.com [223.75.236.241] port 22.

This IP doesn't belong to Github but China Mobile.